# Experiencing Memory leak due to Anonymous Implementation of ValueEventListener in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, memory-leaks, firebase-realtime-database

Recently I am experiencing a memory leak in every Fragment and Activity using Firebase ValueEventListeners. I am not sure why this is happening. Everything was fine until I tried cleaning up my code (like renaming my Fragments, Activities, moving all Model classes to a separate Package). Everything is working fine except for memory leaks.

I have been trying to find the issue for the past few hours but in vain. This is how I use ValueEventListeners in Every Fragment and Activity.

```
private ValueEventListener articleListener;
```

In onCreate(), I create a method which returns `ValueEventListener`

```
private ValueEventListener articleListener() {
    articleListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ModelImage model = dataSnapshot.getValue(ModelImage.class);

            ImageCoverImageUrl = model.getImageCoverImageUrl();
            ImageTitle = model.getImageTitle();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {/*Do Nothing*/}
    };
    return articleListener;
}
```

Now define Database Reference.

```
dbArticle = dbRoot
   .child(getResources().getString(R.string.Child_Articles))
   .child(ArticleLanguage)
```

and then this line of code

```
dbArticle.addValueEventListener(articleListener());
```

and finally inside onDestroy(),

```
if (dbArticle != null && articleListener != null) {
   dbArticle.removeEventListener(articleListener);
}
```

And finally here is the screenshot of leak canary.

[image]

PS: I haven't used any anonymous ValueEventListeners in any of my Activity/Fragments. Yet, every Activity and Fragment leaks memory with the following information in LeakCanary

[image]

BTW. **I am still using the Firebase library version 10.2.6**

Can someone help me identify, what went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't worked a lot with leak canary, but in my limited experience I received some false positive leaks from it. Maybe you want to track your memory and see if there is really a leak. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-monitor.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the listener in `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods, according to the activity life-cycle. You need to remember that `onDestroy()` method is not always called.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Alex is right, the best way to set listeners is in onStart method and remove them in onStop method.

Comment: Since I was using `onFinish()` in `onBackPressed` in Activities, I was assuming `onDestroy()` will be called. But you may be right about onDestroy() in Fragment (in my case). I will try this out in a Fragment and Activity and get back to you.

Comment: I have a ValueEventListener inside onClickListener. Where should I remove the Listener (I mean in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`)?

Comment: If you added the listener in `onStarted()` method then you have to remove it in `onStoped()` and if you have added the listener in `onResumed()`  method, then you have to remove it in `onPaused()'. This is how it works.

Comment: I can understand that. Now I have moved all the Firebase Listeners to `onStart()` except for one Firebase Listener which remains inside a method. This method is executed on clicking the Menu Button. I am also removing all the Firebase Listeners in `onStop()`. Yet, I am still receiving a memory leak due to Firebase listener. Hence my above question.

Comment: You did this in your fragment or in your activity?

Comment: in my Fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148878/discussion-between-user3314337-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Yet I did move my Firebase Listener from onCreate to onStart. I am removing the Listener in onStop(). Yet there arises a leak.
Yes. According to Leak Canary, the Activity still leaks an instance (100kB)

Comment: Ok, you moved those in the method of your activity not of your fragment, correct?

Comment: There are Listeners in both Activity and Fragment. Hence changes (as mentioned above) have been made in both Activity and Fragment. Should I post the Code for Activity and Fragment? It will give you a better idea.